# GoogleSheets script to sendEmail upon form submission, how should I handle a formatting error for a blank cell?

Tags: javascript, sendmail

Simple call logger/lead sheet generator using Google Forms and a script to send out the lead upon submission.  I'm getting a format error when the user does not input a date into the field. I don't want to require an appt. time/date in the form. Here is my code:

```js
function sendEmails() {

  //gets list of 
  var leadss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("LatestLeadSheet");
  var leadList = leadss.getRange(3, 1, leadss.getLastRow() - 2, leadss.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var timeZone = Session.getScriptTimeZone();


  var today = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timeZone, "MM/dd/yyyy"); //Today's date for email subject line
  var fullMessage = ""; //clears fullMessage variable

  // Creates body of email. Looping through each array from LatestLeadSheet tab 
  for (var j = 0; j < leadList.length; j++) {

    var message = "Client Name: " + leadList[j][1] + "\n" +
      "Client Phone: " + leadList[j][3] + "\n" +
      "Client Email: " + leadList[j][8] + "\n" +
      "Interested in: " + leadList[j][5] + "\n" +
      "Quoted rate of: " + leadList[j][6] + "\n" +
      "Notes: " + leadList[j][7] + "\n" +
      "Appointment Set for: " + Utilities.formatDate(leadList[j][10], timeZone, "HH:mm  MM/dd/yyyy") + "\n"
      //+"At: "+Utilities.formatDate(leadList[j][11],timeZone,"h:mm a") + "\n\n"
      +
      "Referral Source: " + leadList[j][2] + "\n" +
      "Other Info: " + leadList[j][4] + "\n" +
      "Documents were sent (Y/N): " + leadList[j][9] + "\n" +
      "Call was taken at: " + Utilities.formatDate(leadList[j][0], timeZone, "HH:mm  MM/dd/yyyy") + "\n" +
      "Call was logged by: " + leadList[j][12] + "\n\n\n\n";
    var fullMessage = fullMessage + message;
  }

  //Sends email to each recipient listed on SalesTeam tab  
  var subject = "DMS Call Sheet from: " + today;
  var emailss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("SalesTeam");
  var lr = emailss.getLastRow();

  for (var i = 2; i <= lr; i++) {

    var currentEmail = emailss.getRange(i, 2).getValue();
    MailApp.sendEmail(currentEmail, subject, "Please follow up with the following potential clients: \n\n" + fullMessage)
  }

}
```

Comment: I cannot understand about `an appt. time/date in the form` and your goal. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of them?

Comment: I solved my issue.  I added a ternary operator ahead of the message concatenation.  Basically checking to see if that cell was empty or not.  If empty added a string, if not used the date that was in there.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.